# Avoid Pagebreak In Appendix

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, appendices

I am trying to get the headings on the same page and have already tried using `/nopagebreak` and `samepage`, however it will still break the page. As to my understanding, the pdf size should be small enough for the headings to be displayed in one page.

So it should be

```
Anhang
A Gesetzesauszüge
A.1 Gesetzesauszug Zivilrecht: Art. 3, Abs. 1
Sōzoku no kōryoku. Sōsoku [Auswirkungen der Vererbung. Vererbung] (1947): Art. 3, Abs. 1.
```

in one page:
[used pdf](https://docdro.id/qxfQD5x)

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }

\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}% 
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,% positive value, if afterindent=false is set
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for section entries
   ]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subparagraph}
  \usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\newcommand*\appendixmore{
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\counterwithout{table}{section}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\appendix
\addsec{\appendixname}
\subsection{Gesetzesauszüge}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.7,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}\subsubsection{Gesetzesauszug Zivilrecht: Art. 3, Abs. 1}\label{ssec:heir3} \normalsize{Sōzoku no kōryoku. Sōsoku [Auswirkungen der Vererbung. Vererbung] (1947): Art. 3, Abs. 1.}]{heir.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2,scale=0.7,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}\subsubsection{Gesetzesauszug Zivilrecht: Art. 7, Abs. 3.}\label{ssec:heir7} \normalsize{Iden no kōryoku. Hōkatsu juisha no kenri gimu [Willenswirkung. Umfassende Rechte und Pflichten der Begünstigten] (1947): Art. 7, Abs. 3}]{heir.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `\addsec` and the `\subsection` command to the `pagecommand` option of the first page:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,headings=Standardklasse,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}% 
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,% positive value, if afterindent=false is set
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for section entries
   ]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection,subsubsection}
\newcommand*\appendixmore{
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}% loads also graphicx

\begin{document}
\appendix
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.7,
  pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}%
              \addsec{\appendixname}\subsection{Gesetzesauszüge}% <- moved
              \subsubsection{Gesetzesauszug Zivilrecht: Art. 3, Abs. 1}\label{ssec:heir3}%
              %\normalsize
              {Sōzoku no kōryoku. Sōsoku [Auswirkungen der Vererbung. Vererbung] (1947): Art. 3, Abs. 1.}%
]{heir.pdf}
\includepdf[
  pages=2,scale=0.7,
  pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}%
              \subsubsection{Gesetzesauszug Zivilrecht: Art. 7, Abs. 3.}\label{ssec:heir7}%
              %\normalsize
              {Iden no kōryoku. Hōkatsu juisha no kenri gimu [Willenswirkung. Umfassende Rechte und Pflichten der Begünstigten] (1947): Art. 7, Abs. 3}%
]{heir.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]